# CodeIgniter Basic

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.

I want to know use of $CI =& get_instance();

is this use for error logging or global config variable.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From CodeIgniter manual:

> $CI =& get_instance();
>
> Once you've assigned the object to a
>   variable, you'll use that variable
>   instead of $this:

```
$CI =&get_instance();
```

> 

```
$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url'); etc.
```

> Note: You'll notice that the above
>   get_instance() function is being
>   passed by reference:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

> This is very important. Assigning by
>   reference allows you to use the
>   original CodeIgniter object rather
>   than creating a copy of it.
>
> Also, please note: If you are running
>   PHP 4 it's usually best to avoid
>   calling get_instance() from within
>   your class constructors. PHP 4 has
>   trouble referencing the CI super
>   object within application constructors
>   since objects do not exist until the
>   class is fully instantiated.

Link: 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Only the class that extends CI_Controller,Model,View can use

```
$this->load->library('something');
$this->load->helper('something');//etc
```

Your Custom Class cannot use the above code.
To use the above features in your custom class, your must use

```
$CI=&get instance();
$CI->load->library('something');
$CI->load->helper('something');
```

for example,in your custom class

```
// this following code will not work
Class Car
{
   $this->load->library('something');
   $this->load->helper('something');
}


//this will work
Class Car
{
   $CI=&get_instance();
   $CI->load->library('something');
   $CI->load->helper('something');
}
// Here $CI is a variable.
```